# Jquery code not changing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("p").click(function() {
            alert("button was clicked");
            var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
        });
    });

</script>

<body>
    <p> This text will change </p>
</body>
```

Why does this code not change when clicked??

Comment: What is supposed to change? There is nothing that is changing anything. You make an alert and you set a variable that is not being used when a paragraph is changed. Next issue you can not have an external script and have code inside of it.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mean change but I should get an alert when clicked surely?

Comment: @thedove yes you should get https://fiddle.jshell.net/ys5sk35p/

Comment: exactly, so my question is why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have both code inside a script and have a reference to a script on the same script block. You need to have separate tags for them.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("p").click(function() {
            alert("button was clicked");
            var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
        });
    });

</script>
```

Now when the code runs an alert will appear when you click the paragraph element.

Comment: i will accept in a minute. do you also know how to refer to different buttons within jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If you, by any chance, want to change the text inside the paragraph, this is what you should do:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("p").click(function() {
        alert("button was clicked");
        var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
        $("p").text(numbers);
    });
});
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/grrf6c7w/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `variable` you defined as the text of `p`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var $numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  $("p").click(function() {
    
    $("p").text($numbers)
    
    alert("button was clicked");
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This text will change</p>
```